# Time-dependent effects in flexible parametric survival model compared to Cox-model

Tags: survival, cox-model, splines, nonparametric, time-varying-covariate

My question is a theoretical one. In my research I am interested in the (functional form of) time-dependency of a specific covariate effect on the hazard rate. Next to that I have no real interest in prediction.

Whereas I don't want to limit myself to a linear interaction term with time, or log(time) I am looking for alternatives. In general, these linear interactions are proposed in a Cox model and not much literature has been written on including more flexible time-dependent effects in this model.
However, Royston and Parmar (*flexible parametric survival analysis using stata: beyond the Cox model*) proposed a flexible parametric survival model in which the log cumulative hazard rate is being modelled as a spline version of time and complex time-dependencies can be included as well (interactions with a spline of time). They describe the inclusion of time-dependencies as one of the advantages of the model for several reasons: ease of use, there is no widely accepted approach in the Cox model and the robustness of their estimates should be better. To me the nature of these arguments are more of a practical point of view instead of of a profound 'statistical' nature. To be more precise: I believe in the Cox model there also is a possibility to include an interaction term with a flexible functional form of time (spline) and I think this should give me approximately the same results. An extra advantage in this case would be that we would not have to worry about a baseline hazard function (since I am not interested in prediction). But these methods are very rarely used in the literature (see for example: *Parsimonious analysis of time-dependent effects in the Cox model* of Lehr and Schemper).

My question thus: is it indeed the case that Cox models also can include complex time-dependencies and that this should give me more or less the same results as the Royston-Parmar model or is there something I am missing out on and is the Royston-Parmar model defintely the better choice?